# R, dealing with NA in if statement for creating a new binaire variable , just removing NA not an option

Tags: r, if-statement, na

My data has many columns and subjects, but to illustrate it simpler, lets say I have 3 subjects with 5 variables/columns called x1, x2 and x3, x4 and x5. In the analysis that I want it is important I actually call the columns I want to use (since I cannot just use the whole dataframe in my analysis because there are more variables/columns there, variables/columns like x1 and x5 I do not want to use for this specific task, )
The classes of my columns are: character

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), x1=c('frhd', 'rthd','rthj','rtrp'), x2=c(5,1,4, NA), 
                  x3=c(4,1,NA, NA), x4=c(3, NA,NA, NA), x5 = c('blae', 'blq', 'ctli', 'wrrv'))

    id   x1     x2  x3  x4  x5
    1   frhd    5   4   3   blae
    2   rthd    1   1   NA  blq
    3   rthj    4   NA  NA  ctli
    4   rtrp    NA  NA  NA  wrrv
```

I want to create column x6.
x6 should be labeled as 1 if x2 or x3 or x4 == "4", if it does not, then 0. If x2 *and* x3 *and* x4 are NA, then X6 should be labeled as NA, this works. The problem I have now is that I get NA as outcome even if not all x2 and x3 and x4 are NA. Just 1 NA in the whole row already turns x6 into an NA. So, for row 2, x6, I get NA, but I want 0.  For row 3 , x6 I get NA, but i want 1. 
See table below

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), x1=c('frhd', 'rthd','rthj','rtrp'), x2=c(5,1,4, NA), 
                  x3=c(4,1,NA, NA), x4=c(3, NA,NA, NA), x5 = c('blae', 'blq', 'ctli', 'wrrv'), x6iwant=c(1, 0, 1, NA), x6iget=c(1, NA,NA,NA))

    id  x1     x2   x3  x4  x5    x6iwant x6iget    
    1   frhd    5   4   3   blae    1       1
    2   rthd    1   1   NA  blq     0       NA
    3   rthj    4   NA  NA  ctli    1       NA
    4   rtrp    NA  NA  NA  wrrv    NA      NA
```

At the bottum is the code that I have and would like to further build on/improve if possible. I’ve done quite some searching and trials but nothing seems to work. Sometimes I want NA as outcome, sometimes I don’t. I think that’s what makes it complicated. I tried adding na.rm = TRUE in the end, but that does not seem possible with ifelse.
`data$x6 <- ifelse (data$x2 == “4” | data$x3 == “4” | data$x4 == “4”, 1, 0)`
`#create x6, for each row, if x2 or x3 or x4 == "4", then outcome is 1, if not, then 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `apply` function along with a few logical expressions. We use `apply(..., 1, ...)` to loop over the rows of the data (and only select the columns we're interested in). We then check, for each row, if all the values are `NA`, if so, we return `NA`, otherwise we check to see if the value `4` appears in any of the columns.

```
apply(data[,c("x2", "x3","x4")], 1, 
      FUN = function(x) as.numeric(ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, 4 %in% x)))

# [1]  1  0  1 NA
```

Note that your data in `x2`, `x3`, and `x4` appear to be numeric. If it truly is a character value, you just need to surround `4` in quotes (`"4"`):

```
apply(data[,c("x2", "x3","x4")], 1, 
      FUN = function(x) as.numeric(ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, "4" %in% x)))
```